# Automate input into app

Tags: automation

Is there a way to create a script or "app" to automatically input data into an already installed app.
I.e Fill and submit a todo task in a todo app.
Or fill a register form ?

Answer (score 3):

In every device, there is a binary called `input`.
You can invoke it with from your application or even from adb:

```
$ adb shell input
Usage: input [<source>] <command> [<arg>...]
The sources are:
      mouse
      keyboard
      joystick
      touchnavigation
      touchpad
      trackball
      stylus
      dpad
      touchscreen
      gamepad

The commands and default sources are:
      text <string> (Default: touchscreen)
      keyevent [--longpress] <key code number or name> ... (Default: keyboard)
      tap <x> <y> (Default: touchscreen)
      swipe <x1> <y1> <x2> <y2> [duration(ms)] (Default: touchscreen)
      press (Default: trackball)
      roll <dx> <dy> (Default: trackball)
```

You can then navigate int the app using [KeyEvent](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/KeyEvent.java), click buttons, submit text to the focused element, etc.